# SwiftUI - get user defaults in a view model in combination with a Json file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Please help, I have a view model, local json and I would like to use user defaults in this that view model so I can load and then modify it and to be able clear the selected items with one button created in a view. In view I used `@AppStorage` and it works as expected. Now I'm trying to create view model also using app storage or user defaults instead of heaving it in a view.

Model:

```
import Foundation

struct CountriesSection: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable  {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var items: [Country]
}

struct Country: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable,Hashable  {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isOn: Bool = false
}
```

View model:

```
import Foundation

class ItemSelectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var itemSections: [CountriesSection] = []

    init(){
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData()  {
        
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "countries", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([CountriesSection].self, from: data)
            //UserDefaults.standard.set(sections, forKey: "saved1")
            self.itemSections = sections
        } catch {
            print("failed loading or decoding with error: ", error)
        }
    }
    
    func getSelectedItemsCount() -> Int{
        var i: Int = 0
        for itemSection in itemSections {
            let filteredItems = itemSection.items.filter { item in
                return item.isOn
            }
            i = i + filteredItems.count
        }
        return i
    }
}

extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }
    
    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    //@StateObject var viewModel = ItemSelectionViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ItemSelectionViewModel
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            CheckItemView()
            Total().multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Spacer()
            Button("Clear seclections"){
                viewModel.itemSections = []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Total view:

```
import SwiftUI


struct Total: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ItemSelectionViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center){
            Text("Number of checked items:  \($viewModel.getSelectedItemsCount)")
            .padding()
        }}
}

struct Total_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Total()
    }
}
```

CheckItemView

```
import SwiftUI

struct CheckItemView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ItemSelectionViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack() {
                List(){
                    ForEach(viewModel.itemSections.indices, id: \.self){ id in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ItemSectionDetailedView(
                            items: $viewModel.itemSections[id].items)) {
                                
                                Text(viewModel.itemSections[id].name)
                                
                            }
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

ItemSectionDetailedView view

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemSectionDetailedView: View {
   
   
    @Binding var items: [Country]
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView() {
                ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self){ id in
                    HStack{
                        Toggle(items[id].name, isOn: $items[id].isOn).toggleStyle(CheckToggleStyle()).tint(.mint)
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .topLeading)
        }
    }
}

struct CheckToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label {
                configuration.label
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
                    .foregroundColor(configuration.isOn ? .accentColor : .secondary)
                    .accessibility(label: Text(configuration.isOn ? "Checked" : "Unchecked"))
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

Main view:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var varModel = ItemSelectionViewModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(varModel)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: And your question/issue is?

Comment: where to put user defaults in view model to get it working?

Comment: In SwiftUI we call this class a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t have to load your data from JSON all the time. Load it only if the `itemsSections` collection is empty. Use `@AppStorage` in the Viewmodel the same way you use it in a view:

```
class ItemSelectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //Change this to @AppStorage
    @AppStorage("saved1") var itemSections: [CountriesSection] = []

    init(){
        
        //load data only if there are no items in your array
        if itemSections.isEmpty{
            loadData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData()  {
        
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "countries", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([CountriesSection].self, from: data)
            self.itemSections = sections
        } catch {
            print("failed loading or decoding with error: ", error)
        }
    }
    
    func getSelectedItemsCount() -> Int{
        var i: Int = 0
        for itemSection in itemSections {
            let filteredItems = itemSection.items.filter { item in
                return item.isOn
            }
            i = i + filteredItems.count
        }
        return i
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Regarding your comment on clearing the `Userdefaults`. You don´t need this anymore. You can also delete the extension if it is not needed anywhere else. To reset the collection just do:

```
Button("Clear seclections"){
    viewmodel.itemsSections = []
}
```

as you will find out this won´t work. Because your Viewmodel is only in your `CheckItemView`. But it is in the wrong place anyway. Pull it up to `ContentView` and pass it on either through the `.environment(...` or as var. Your `Total` view should also get the same `Viewmodel` instance instead of creating a new one.

### Edit2:

I was deriving my solution from the code you provided. In your example you are clearing the `Userdefaults` and as there are no items left there is nothing presented. Solution should be simple:

```
Button("Clear seclections"){
    viewmodel.itemsSections = []
    viewmodel.loadData() // add this
}
```

Comment: it's almost ok like that, probably I did something wrong, I have this button in ContentView and when I click on it it resets the counter but not checked items. Also sometimes it deletes entire view.

Comment: hi, I added MyApp and I put there environmentObject, then I put in every view @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ItemSelectionViewModel.  Did I do that correctly?  I tested it and it deleted entire view not only counter and checks.

Comment: @paulatraveler Seems ok. But what do you mean by `it deleted entire view`?

Comment: I added a screenshot.